# Unable to install sklearn library using command prompt

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pip

I have to install sklearn python library using command prompt, using the command `pip install sklearn` but it is showing the following error.

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python38\python.exe"  "C:\Python38\Scripts\pip.exe" install sklearn': The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
pythom -m pip install --upgrade pip

python -m pip install <package name>
```

This will help.